# Max bytes that can be sent to SQL Server using RODBC's sqlQuery()

Tags: sql-server, r, odbc, rodbc

What is the maximum character string length / bytes that can be sent to SQL Server using RODBC's function `sqlQuery()`? I've been using `sqlQuery()` primarily for updating and inserting records in tables by sending multiple statements in one string, batches. For example, this string has 3 query statements and has a string length / byte size of 146 using `nchar()` when it's not broken up by newlines and spaces.

```
update_queries = "UPDATE tbl SET col1 = newval1 WHERE col2 = val1;
                  UPDATE tbl SET col1 = newval2 WHERE col2 = val2;
                  UPDATE tbl SET col1 = newval3 WHERE col2 = val3;"
```

I can send it off with `sqlQuery(db_conn, update_queries)`, and so this goes back to the question I posted. I've run into this concept of [Network Packet Size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server) from the SQL Server (64 bit) documentation. It states that the maximum batch size is 65,536 * Network Packet Size, where the the default packet size is 4 KB. I assume 65,636 is in bytes so then byte wise it's 65,536 * 4,000 = 262,144,000 bytes. Would 262,144,000 then be the maximum length a string containing valid queries could be? Can someone please clarify if I have the right idea here or is there another SQL Server concept or ODBC concept that I need to know about? Thanks

Comment: Were you really able to successfully run *all* queries in one call or only first statement was run? AFAIK - you can only send one SQL query in ODBC call at a time.

Comment: Yes you can actually send multiple queries in one call.